# django1.8- how to append information manually when uploading Excel and inserting into database

Tags: python, django

[image]

The excel is like the left picture with 3 columns.

When inserting into database, I need to add 2 columns more manually like right picture showed and insert altogether 5 columns in database finally. These 2 additional columns information is fetched from other databases.

And another function is if there is already existing file, the newly uploaded file will override the existing one.[snippets in views.py below]

I have already tried two 3 party tools but not works, so maybe it is still better just to use the one embedded in django.

Version: Python 2.7. Excel 2013. Django1.8.

Any help is highly appreciated. Hope could provide the detail snippet for how to append these 2 columns :

```
uploader = request.session['uploader']
Date=request.session['date']
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from financialdata.storage import OverwriteStorage

class XXXXDataForm(forms.Form):
    XXXXfile=forms.FileField(label='Select a file')
```

**views.py**

```
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

def import_data(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = XXXXForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc= XXXX(docfile=request.FILES['docfile'])
            newdoc.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('homepage'))
        else:
            return HttpResponseBadRequest()
    else:
        form = XXXXForm()
    return render_to_response(
        'dataentry.html',
        {
            'form': form,
            'title': 'Import excel data into database example',
            'header': 'Please upload XXXX.xlsx:',
            'message': 'File Saved!'
        },
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))

<!--How can I embed the following part to previous part?-->

class OverwriteStorage(FileSystemStorage):
    def _save(self, name, content):
        if self.exists(name):
            self.delete(name)
        return super(OverwriteStorage, self)._save(name, content)

    def get_available_name(self, name):
        return name
```

Comment: you dont call your delete function

Comment: @maazza, could you please paste your corrected code below? thanks.

Comment: As @maazza said, you created your function, but you are not calling it. Somewhere in the code you should call it so it runs..

Comment: @qasimalbaqali, thanks, I just uploaded the url. Did you mean to call it in url?

Comment: No. What I mean is you created the `delete` function and that's great, but now you need to call it so simply after you have created the function simply call it as in `delete()`, so that when the form is valid, the function gets created and then it executes right? Remember how do you execute a function? you simply write the function and two brackets to call it. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm

Comment: Why are you creating a nested delete function (that looks like it should be a method, because it takes a `self` parameter)? I'm also pretty sure, django's uploaded file object does not have a `save_book_to_database()` method. It also looks like you --at least partially-- copied contents of the the inner `delete()` from somewhere else. It looks like a mixture of belonging into a form (because you access the fields via `self`). But then `super(self)` doesn't work at all, and `self.__class__._default_manager` works only on model instances.

Comment: @dhke, the save_book_to_base is from a app called django-excel, this function works actually. Initially I want to use the django-cleanup, but that one seems to work on fields defined in models. But mine is a form. Could you please specify your solution in the answers? thanks in advance.

Comment: @qasimalbaqali, hi~the previous method has been discarded. Now a new method is applied, adding a storage.py, but the example I took is defining the field in models.py, but mine is fined in form. Is this the reason why this new method doesn't work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you try to check if a certain file exists with a query, if the file does exist, append the `delete()` function to it that Django supplies. I use that on my app, I created a view that would check for an Image i.e: `image = Images.objects.get_or_404(id=current_image_id)` in my views, and then if that gives me a True, I use the following function `image.delete()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

May be like that:

**I don't run my code, it's an example**

```
if request.method == "POST":
        form = XXXXForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            docfile=request.FILES['docfile']
```

```
        if isinstance(docfile, (InMemoryUploadedFile, TemporaryUploadedFile)):
            book = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=docfile.read(), formatting_info=True, on_demand=True)
        else:
            book = xlrd.open_workbook(filename=docfile, formatting_info=True, on_demand=True)

        sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
        new_csv_file = csv.writer(open('new_filename', 'w'))
        # read file
        for line in range(1, sheet.nrows):
            new_row = [request.session.get('uploader'), request.session.get('date')]
            new_row.extend(sheet.row_values(line))                
            new_csv_file.writerow(new_row)
```

## ...

Comment: Hi @mrvol, actually finally I took an another method using the SQL raw query, it is just a hack, but at least could solve the issues.

Comment: @Héléna If you want insert into DB data, that's most easy. First of all, you need to create model for this data. This is something like with fields `Uploader, Date, Question, Choice, Vote`. After form cleaning, do iterate the file as at bellow example, and create list with values. Then save your list  to DB like this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.bulk_create